# Refer to a page just before a label

Tags: cross-referencing, calculations

Is there a simple way to refer to the page before a certain `\label`? Or is it possible to add or subtract a certain number (like the number of pages of an included PDF)?

Comment: Perhaps the `refcount` package and its `\getpagerefnumber` command is useful here

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes". Could you be a bit more specific as to what you want? Include an example that uses `\pageref` (say) and specify what you want the output to be instead of what it gives naturally. Additionally, do you want to use the features of [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED to correct for my faulty memory (I thought `\pageref` was the macro I sought, but it was, in fact, `\getpagerefnumber`).  Apologies to Christian after the fact, since he cites such an answer in his comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,refcount}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
THE PAGE HAS BEEN RECORDED\label{pg:EQ}.
\lipsum[21-30]
\edef\tmp{0\getpagerefnumber{pg:EQ}}
The page before the notation is \the\numexpr-1+\tmp\relax.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `\pageref` unexpandable?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I seem to recall that it was expandable.  And in this case, it did not complain, being put in an `\edef`.

Comment: Compilation breaks anyway for me -- `\tmp` seems to contain no number. That's what I meant. Try `\meaning\tmp`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It worked in rehearsal.  Let me look further.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for go-ahead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With your help I was able to build a new command for better convenience:
    `\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{lipsum,refcount}  
  
\newcommand\pagerefoffset[2][0]{%  
\edef\tmp{\getpagerefnumber{#2}}%  
\the\numexpr#1+\tmp\relax}  
  
\begin{document}  
\lipsum[1-20]  
THE PAGE HAS BEEN RECORDED\label{pg:EQ}.  
\lipsum[21-30]  
The page before the notation is \pagerefoffset[-1]{pg:EQ}.  
The page with the notation is \pagerefoffset{pg:EQ}.  
\end{document}`