# Refer to the last page of an included PDF

Tags: cross-referencing, pdfpages

I want to refer to the last page of an included PDF document.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document} 
\label{pg:mydoc}
\includepdf[pages=-]{mydoc.pdf}

The included pdf is on pages 
\pageref{pg:mydoc} -- x.

\end{document}
```

x should be the last page of the PDF. I have a solution, but I wonder if there is a more simple one.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pdfpages,refcount}

\newcommand*{\pdfnumberofpages}[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    local doc = epdf.open("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}")
    local pages
    if (doc) then
      pages = doc:getCatalog():getNumPages()
    else
      pages = 0
    end
    tex.write(pages)
  }%
}

\newcommand\pagerefoffset[2][0]{%
\edef\tmp{\getpagerefnumber{#2}}%
\the\numexpr#1+\tmp\relax} 

\begin{document} 

\label{pg:mydoc}
\includepdf[pages=-]{mydoc.pdf}

The included pdf is on pages 
\pageref{pg:mydoc} -- \pagerefoffset[\pdfnumberofpages{mydoc.pdf}-1]{pg:mydoc}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324067/refer-to-a-page-just-before-a-label and `\label{pg:mydoc}` after `\includepdf[pages=-]{mydoc.pdf}`

Comment: But this only works, if the PDF is not at the end of the article and I want to refer to it after it is included. Otherwise refering to the label only results in **??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this. Imho it should also work with more complex `pages` options. It assumes that a document is included only once (you would get multiply labels if not).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\AM@output{\setboolean{AM@endoflist}{false}}
                   {\newpage
                    \label{start-\AM@currentdocname}%
                    \setboolean{AM@endoflist}{false}}
                    {}{\fail}

\patchcmd\AM@output{\global\let\@deferlist\AM@deferlist}
                   {\global\let\@deferlist\AM@deferlist
                    \label{stop-\AM@currentdocname}}
                    {}{\fail}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
The included pdf is on pages
\pageref{start-test-ansinew.pdf} -- \pageref{stop-test-ansinew.pdf}

\includepdf[pages={1-2,4}]{test-ansinew}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it produces `! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \fail {}{\fail}`

Comment: Then  you probably have another pdfpages version. It works with TL15 + 16, but not with TL14.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should have upgraded long ago (still using TL13) ;-)

Comment: does this take logical page numbering into account?

Comment: @naphaneal Why didn't you simply try? It uses normal labels and so work as pagerefs always work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mt}    
\begin{document}
last page is \pageref{mydoc} and last page \pageref{yourdoc}

\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={%
                        \refstepcounter{mt}%
                        \ifnum\value{mt}=\the\pdflastximagepages
                        \phantomsection% if hyperref
                        \label{mydoc}
                        \fi}]{a} 
\setcounter{mt}{0}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={%
                        \refstepcounter{mt}%
                        \ifnum\value{mt}=\the\pdflastximagepages
                        \phantomsection% if hyperref
                        \label{yourdoc}
                        \fi}]{a} 

\end{document}
```