Refer to first and last page of each included PDF
I would like to refer to the first and last pages for each of the several PDF documents I am including in a manuscript using \includepdf. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do that?
I tried the following MWE from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324194/322726
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\AM@output{\setboolean{AM@endoflist}{false}}
                   {\newpage
                    \label{start-\AM@currentdocname}%
                    \setboolean{AM@endoflist}{false}}
                    {}{\fail}

\patchcmd\AM@output{\global\let\@deferlist\AM@deferlist}
                   {\global\let\@deferlist\AM@deferlist
                    \label{stop-\AM@currentdocname}}
                    {}{\fail}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
The included pdf is on pages
\pageref{start-test-ansinew.pdf} -- \pageref{stop-test-ansinew.pdf}

\includepdf[pages={1-2,4}]{test-ansinew}

\end{document}

but I get the error message (using pdfLatex and TexLive 2024):
! Undefined control sequence. \fail {}{\fail}

Didn't you already ask this an hour or two ago? And people asked to see some code instead of just a cryptic reference to "the main answer" from another post which still left it unclear which of the answers you referred to?

I deleted my previous post and reformulated the question in a different manner: since I don’t know how to do this, I am just asking, without referring to any already existing post. Thus, there shouldn’t be any confusion anymore now…

Yes, but like this you are withholding information from the users who use their free time to help you. State what you already found and where, show an example in your question with the corresponding error message and maybe add that you are open to other approaches as well.

Welcome (again). Please also state your engine and format. Some of the answers to the question you linked earlier are engine-specific and they are all format-specific. Your engine is something like pdfTeX or LuaTeX. Your format is probably LaTeX, though that is not obvious from this question.

I hope my question now looks more meaningful and exhaustive.

That is much better. Thanks for editing. I suspect the problem is that Ulrike's code is patching internals which have changed since that answer was written.

@FrancescoB Thanks for editing! Much better!

This is a very simple modification of Ulrike Fischer's answer:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\AM@output@i{\setboolean{AM@endoflist}{false}}
{\newpage
  \label{start-\AM@currentdocname}%
  \setboolean{AM@endoflist}{false}}
{}{\fail}

\patchcmd\AM@output@i{\global\let\@deferlist\AM@deferlist}
{\global\let\@deferlist\AM@deferlist
  \label{stop-\AM@currentdocname}}
{}{\fail}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
  The included pdf is on pages
  \pageref{start-kantlipsum.pdf} -- \pageref{stop-kantlipsum.pdf}
  
  \includepdf[pages={1-2,4}]{kantlipsum}
  
\end{document}

kantlipsum.pdf is just the result of compiling
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-20]
\end{document}


Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for.

On the other hand, I realized that if one adds a blank page before \includepdf, then the first (just first, not last) page number of the PDF is decreased by one, like 20 instead of 21:
\afterpage{\blankpage}
\includepdf[scale=0.95,pagecommand={},pages=1-, angle=0]{pdf-filename}
where \blankpage is defined as follows:
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\newpage}
If I remove the blank page, the first PDF page is 21 as expected. I was wondering if there is any way to circumvent this.

@FrancescoB I'd recommend asking a new question and linking this one. The problem is that this is essentially Ulrike's code and not mine and ... well, I am not Ulrike or even vaguely close to Ulrike. All I did was search through the current version of pdfpages.sty to find the macro she patched and figure out from there which other macro needed to be patched instead by now. But I'm also not entirely sure what you're doing. You could try \clearpage in place of \newpage. But I think starting a new shipout during shipout is inevitably going to confuse things. There is probably a better way.

But you'd need to explain the goal in order for people to suggest alternatives. It's a bit hard to visualise, especially with inline code in comments where the % gets confused. I was originally going to post a different answer, but my code relies on primitives which are engine-specific.

@FrancescoB Actually, thinking about this, maybe it is just a matter of ordering and hooks?

Sorry, it's been super hectic over the last weeks and I couldn't reply to your comment. I asked a new question about this subject, hoping it's quite well formulated. Thanks!
